# Loop Array Making Me Loopy

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, filestream

So i have been at this same example problem for a week now. I know that it may
seem easy, but i am finding that the more i look at it or alter it, the more
confused i get. I feel like i am making this a lot more difficult than it
needs to be. The array that i loaded displays correctly in the `Try-Catch` section, but i need to display it in its own method, which i call `listOfAges()`. What would this look like? Any responses are appreciated, please help.

```
class ArrayDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] anArray;
    int ageCount = 0;
    int age;
    String filename = "ageData.dat";

    anArray = new int[50];
    /* The file has 50 numbers which represent an employee's age */
    try {
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));

        while (infile.hasNext()) {

            age = infile.nextInt();
            ageCount += 1;

            System.out.println(ageCount + ". " + age + "\n");
            /* 
             * When i run just this, the output is correct...
             * 
             * But i don't want the output here, i just want to gather 
             * the information from the file and place it at the bottom inside
             *  the method displayAges().*/

        }

        infile.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ageCount = -1;
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    public void listOfAges() {
        System.out.print("  I want to display the data gathered from ageData.dat in this method  ");
        System.out.print("  Also, i receive this error message when i try: 'Illegal modifier for parameter listOfAges; only final is permitted'  ")
    }  


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to store your values in your array:

```
while (infile.hasNext()) {
    age = infile.nextInt();
    anArray[ageCount] = age;
    ageCount += 1;
}
```

Your next problem is that you defined your `listOfAges()` method *inside* your `main()` method. The definition must be outside. You also need to pass your array as an argument to your method so that you can iterate over the array values to print them:

```
public void listOfAges(int[] ages) {
    // use a loop here to print all your array contents
}
```

Comment: these examples are exactly what i was struggling with, extremely helpful guys. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you want to display each element in the array in your method. Your first problem is that the main method is static and you're trying to call a method that isn't static (listOfAges). Change this by simply adding the word static to the method to make it static. You also put this method in the main method. You'll need to move it outside of the brackets.

Second, to display the content you need to loop through it but the array you're holding the data in needs to be outside of the main method. Instead of having

```
int[] anArray;
```

In the main method, delete that and move it above the declaration of the main method. You'll also need to make it a static variable.

```
static int[] anArray;
```

Finally in the listOfAges, add the code to loop through it.

```
for (int i = 0; i  < anArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(anArray.length + ". " + anArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but here:

At

} infile.close(); } catch (IOException ex) { ageCount = -1; ex.printStackTrace(); }

In your  While.infile  loop you're closing your while loop on the } infile.close() instead of opening a new one. So just change it to { infile.close (); } instead...

Since I'm not sure what you're exactly asking this will be the best answer I can give youx , hope I helped.